# Need Help Using If Statements and Lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am new to python and am having a hard time figuring out where my issue begins, I believe that I am mis-defining the variable "primes" in my first if statement. I appreciate the help. The paragraph below is of the task that I am trying to accomplish.

Take a number from the user. Respond with the word "Unitary" if the number is 1, with the word "Prime" if the number is in the list and with the word "Composite" otherwise.

```
primes = [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,
31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,
73,79,83,89,97,101,103,107,109,113,
127,131,137,139,149,151,157,163,167,173,
179,181,191,193,197,199,211,223,227,229,
233,239,241,251,257,263,269,271,277,281,
283,293,307,311,313,317,331,337,347,349,
353,359,367,373,379,383,389,397,401,409,
419,421,431,433,439,443,449,457,461,463,
67,479,487,491,499,503,509,521,523,541,
547,557,563,569,571,577,587,593,599,601,
607,613,617,619,631,641,643,647,653,659,
661,673,677,683,691,701,709,719,727,733,
739,743,751,757,761,769,773,787,797,809,
811,821,823,827,829,839,853,857,859,863,
877,881,883,887,907,911,919,929,937,941,
947,953,967,971,977,983,991,997,1009,1013,
1019,1021,1031,1033,1039,1049,1051,1061,1063,1069,
1087,1091,1093,1097,1103,1109,1117,1123,1129,1151,
1153,1163,1171,1181,1187,1193,1201,1213,1217,1223,
1229,1231,1237,1249,1259,1277,1279,1283,1289,1291,
1297,1301,1303,1307,1319,1321,1327,1361,1367,1373,
1381,1399,1409,1423,1427,1429,1433,1439,1447,1451,
1453,1459,1471,1481,1483,1487,1489,1493,1499,1511,
1523,1531,1543,1549,1553,1559,1567,1571,1579,1583,
1597,1601,1607,1609,1613,1619,1621,1627,1637,1657,
1663,1667,1669,1693,1697,1699,1709,1721,1723,1733,
1741,1747,1753,1759,1777,1783,1787,1789,1801,1811,
1823,1831,1847,1861,1867,1871,1873,1877,1879,1889,
1901,1907,1913,1931,1933,1949,1951,1973,1979,1987,
1993,1997,1999,2003,2011,2017,2027,2029,2039,2053,
2063,2069,2081,2083,2087,2089,2099,2111,2113,2129,
2131,2137,2141,2143,2153,2161,2179,2203,2207,2213,
2221,2237,2239,2243,2251,2267,2269,2273,2281,2287,
293,2297,2309,2311,2333,2339,2341,2347,2351,2357,
2371,2377,2381,2383,2389,2393,2399,2411,2417,2423,
2437,2441,2447,2459,2467,2473,2477,2503,2521,2531,
2539,2543,2549,2551,2557,2579,2591,2593,2609,2617,
2621,2633,2647,2657,2659,2663,2671,2677,2683,2687,
2689,2693,2699,2707,2711,2713,2719,2729,2731,2741,
2749,2753,2767,2777,2789,2791,2797,2801,2803,2819,
2833,2837,2843,2851,2857,2861,2879,2887,2897,2903,
2909,2917,2927,2939,2953,2957,2963,2969,2971,2999,
3001,3011,3019,3023,3037,3041,3049,3061,3067,3079,
3083,3089,3109,3119,3121,3137,3163,3167,3169,3181,
3187,3191,3203,3209,3217,3221,3229,3251,3253,3257,
3259,3271,3299,3301,3307,3313,3319,3323,3329,3331,
3343,3347,3359,3361,3371,3373,3389,3391,3407,3413,
3433,3449,3457,3461,3463,3467,3469,3491,3499,3511,
3517,3527,3529,3533,3539,3541,3547,3557,3559,3571,
3581,3583,3593,3607,3613,3617,3623,3631,3637,3643,
3659,3671,3673,3677,3691,3697,3701,3709,3719,3727,
3733,3739,3761,3767,3769,3779,3793,3797,3803,3821,
3823,3833,3847,3851,3853,3863,3877,3881,3889,3907,
3911,3917,3919,3923,3929,3931,3943,3947,3967,3989,
4001,4003,4007,4013,4019,4021,4027,4049,4051,4057,
4073,4079,4091,4093,4099,4111,4127,4129,4133,4139,
4153,4157,4159,4177,4201,4211,4217,4219,4229,4231,
4241,4243,4253,4259,4261,4271,4273,4283,4289,4297,
4327,4337,4339,4349,4357,4363,4373,4391,4397,4409,
4421,4423,4441,4447,4451,4457,4463,4481,4483,4493,
4507,4513,4517,4519,4523,4547,4549,4561,4567,4583,
4591,4597,4603,4621,4637,4639,4643,4649,4651,4657,
4663,4673,4679,4691,4703,4721,4723,4729,4733,4751,
4759,4783,4787,4789,4793,4799,4801,4813,4817,4831,
4861,4871,4877,4889,4903,4909,4919,4931,4933,4937,
4943,4951,4957,4967,4969,4973,4987,4993,4999,5003,
5009,5011,5021,5023,5039,5051,5059,5077,5081,5087,
5099,5101,5107,5113,5119,5147,5153,5167,5171,5179,
5189,5197,5209,5227,5231,5233,5237,5261,5273,5279,
5281,5297,5303,5309,5323,5333,5347,5351,5381,5387,
5393,5399,5407,5413,5417,5419,5431,5437,5441,5443,
5449,5471,5477,5479,5483,5501,5503,5507,5519,5521,
5527,5531,5557,5563,5569,5573,5581,5591,5623,5639,
5641,5647,5651,5653,5657,5659,5669,5683,5689,5693,
5701,5711,5717,5737,5741,5743,5749,5779,5783,5791,
5801,5807,5813,5821,5827,5839,5843,5849,5851,5857,
5861,5867,5869,5879,5881,5897,5903,5923,5927,5939,
5953,5981,5987,6007,6011,6029,6037,6043,6047,6053,
6067,6073,6079,6089,6091,6101,6113,6121,6131,6133,
6143,6151,6163,6173,6197,6199,6203,6211,6217,6221,
6229,6247,6257,6263,6269,6271,6277,6287,6299,6301,
6311,6317,6323,6329,6337,6343,6353,6359,6361,6367,
6373,6379,6389,6397,6421,6427,6449,6451,6469,6473,
6481,6491,6521,6529,6547,6551,6553,6563,6569,6571,
6577,6581,6599,6607,6619,6637,6653,6659,6661,6673,
6679,6689,6691,6701,6703,6709,6719,6733,6737,6761,
6763,6779,6781,6791,6793,6803,6823,6827,6829,6833,
6841,6857,6863,6869,6871,6883,6899,6907,6911,6917,
6947,6949,6959,6961,6967,6971,6977,6983,6991,6997,
7001,7013,7019,7027,7039,7043,7057,7069,7079,7103,
7109,7121,7127,7129,7151,7159,7177,7187,7193,7207,
7211,7213,7219,7229,7237,7243,7247,7253,7283,7297,
7307,7309,7321,7331,7333,7349,7351,7369,7393,7411,
7417,7433,7451,7457,7459,7477,7481,7487,7489,7499,
7507,7517,7523,7529,7537,7541,7547,7549,7559,7561,
7573,7577,7583,7589,7591,7603,7607,7621,7639,7643,
7649,7669,7673,7681,7687,7691,7699,7703,7717,7723,
7727,7741,7753,7757,7759,7789,7793,7817,7823,7829,
7841,7853,7867,7873,7877,7879,7883,7901,7907,7919,
7927,7933,7937,7949,7951,7963,7993,8009,8011,8017,
8039,8053,8059,8069,8081,8087,8089,8093,8101,8111,
8117,8123,8147,8161,8167,8171,8179,8191,8209,8219,
8221,8231,8233,8237,8243,8263,8269,8273,8287,8291,
8293,8297,8311,8317,8329,8353,8363,8369,8377,8387,
8389,8419,8423,8429,8431,8443,8447,8461,8467,8501,
8513,8521,8527,8537,8539,8543,8563,8573,8581,8597,
8599,8609,8623,8627,8629,8641,8647,8663,8669,8677,
8681,8689,8693,8699,8707,8713,8719,8731,8737,8741,
8747,8753,8761,8779,8783,8803,8807,8819,8821,8831,
8837,8839,8849,8861,8863,8867,8887,8893,8923,8929,
8933,8941,8951,8963,8969,8971,8999,9001,9007,9011,
9013,9029,9041,9043,9049,9059,9067,9091,9103,9109,
9127,9133,9137,9151,9157,9161,9173,9181,9187,9199,
9203,9209,9221,9227,9239,9241,9257,9277,9281,9283,
9293,9311,9319,9323,9337,9341,9343,9349,9371,9377,
9391,9397,9403,9413,9419,9421,9431,9433,9437,9439,
9461,9463,9467,9473,9479,9491,9497,9511,9521,9533,
9539,9547,9551,9587,9601,9613,9619,9623,9629,9631,
9643,9649,9661,9677,9679,9689,9697,9719,9721,9733,
9739,9743,9749,9767,9769,9781,9787,9791,9803,9811,
9817,9829,9833,9839,9851,9857,9859,9871,9883,9887,
9901,9907,9923,9929,9931,9941,9949,9967,9973,10007]

number = int(input("Choose A Number"))
if number == primes:print("Primes")
elif number == 1: print("Unitary")
else: print("Composite")
```

Comment: oneliner if else state ments are btw generaly bad practice

Comment: You didn't really need to post all those numbers.

Comment: When you are doing `number == primes` you are testing if your number is equal to the primes variable. When you want to do is to check if your number belong to the prime array. This is done with the `in` operator

Answer (score 4):

Should be

`if number in primes`

(not `if number == primes`)

Answer (score 1):

```
number = int(input("Choose A Number"))
if number in primes:
    print("Primes")
elif number == 1:
    print("Unitary")
else:
    print("Composite")
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `if` line with

```
if number in primes:
```